# How do I interpret this Request Header to a plain sentence?

Tags: http, ntlm, request-headers, negotiate

Can you explain in one sentence what is requested by the Request Header below? 
(So that I can find explanation of each term :Negotiate, Basic-realm, NTLM)

> **WWW-Authenticate**  Negotiate NTLM Basic realm="localhost"

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any helpful answers?

Answer (score 0):

It's a broken header, unless you missed a few commas.

Comment: OK. There are line-break between each; I pasted from FireBug

Answer (score 0):

The header is saying that the server is expecting you to authenticate.

It will accept NTLM (Windows NT Lan Manager) or Basic authentication, and when you send it back, use the realm "localhost".

Your next request should include an HTTP Authentication: XXXXXX header with appropriate authentication for the request you're making.